# what is the different between eclipse Galileo and eclipse Helios?

Tags: eclipse, windows-7-x64

I'm interested in knowing the differences between these two versions. If I would opt for the latest, which one would that be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Galileo is version 3.5.*, Helios is version 3.6.*. Helios is the latest.

You should use the more recent version unless you depend on something that only exists in an older version. In that case, try to kill the dependency ASAP.

As for which one is better, I don't know (and won't answer). They're very similar.

Comment: @wingdings just replace it if it bothers you. Please, for the love of God, don't use an older version just because you don't like the new version's icon

Comment: It might also be helpful for to know for the future that Eclipse releases are named in alphabetical order. H > G, etc. The next release (Summery of 2011) is named Indigo. See the other answer for new and noteworthy of at least the core eclipse. You will have to search separately for documents from other plugins that you are likely using. The graphics you are referring to isn't related to a release, it's the branding of the Eclipse IDE for Java EE developers package. Other packages have different branding. If you don't like, install the basic package and add Java EE plugins from update site.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Helios New And Noteworthy](ftp://ftp.ulakbim.gov.tr/eclipse/eclipseMirror/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.6-201006080911/eclipse-news.html) for a quick visual overview of what changed in Helios (3.6).

If you really what to know the details, you can look at the [closed bug / added feature list](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?chfieldto=Now;query_format=advanced;chfieldfrom=2009-09-01;bug_status=CLOSED;).